# Insert into annotation parameter from method where annotation is used

Tags: java, annotations

I couldnt find an answer and better question.

I'm using my annotation in some class method like below

```
@MyAnnotation(name = "a", test1 = "test")
public void testIt(Long name5, String test5){
...
}
```

what I'm trying to achieve is to use parametr from method `testIt` and put them into `@MyAnnotation`, e.g:

```
@MyAnnotation(name = name5, test1 = test5)
public void testIt(Long name5, String test5){
...
}
```

name5 and test5 are methods parameters
but ofc it doesnt work that way. Any idea how to achieve that if its possible?

also I have some Enum which i'd like to put into `@MyAnnotation`, is it possible too?

Comment: An annotation (and its parameters) is static at the moment of compilation and cannot be changed any more. Can you please document the problem you want so solve with this impossible custruct?

Comment: i dont want to change it. I gave two examples, first which works ofc, and second which shows how i'd like to use it. I want to give parameters to annotation from method's parameters

Comment: yeah probably because of my bad english you didnt understand me. I dont want to have names of mine parameters, I want to have values of this parameters when methods is called. e.g someone use `testIt(5L,"test")` and I want to insert 5L and test into `@MyAnnotation`.

Comment: This is what I meant with the parameters values of an annotation are static. You can define annotatate your method with `@MyAnnotation(name = "a", test1 = "test")`, but then these values are fix from the time of the compilation. When you do `((MyAnnotation)Myclass.class.getMethod(...).getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class).name()`, what do you expect to be returned if the values of the annotation would be dependent on the methods parameters values (which is currenly not called)

Comment: Clearly you have more knowgledge about it, I dont doubt it. I just dont understand you completly, you telling me its impossible because parameters in methods are changing? `MyAnnocation` construct himself when `testIt(..)` is called so it should have parameters that won't change before method

Comment: You can call the method `testIt()` serverals times (`testIt(5,"bla");testIt(6,"blubb");`) which value do you expect to be returned when you call the static introspection `((MyAnnotation)Myclass.class.getMethod(...).getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class).n‌​ame()`

Comment: Bear in mind that annotations provide meta data on a _method_ not meta data on a particular invocation of a method.

Answer (score 0):

It works with `@MyAnnotation(name = "#name5", test1 = "#test5")`

Comment: This is not enough, it goes as text in the annotation. Should there be some parser somewhere configured?